# how to attach div to javascript document.write?

Tags: javascript

```js
  document.write("<div class='element'> "<img src='images/smileys/" + newArray[i] + "'/>"+ i + </div>");
```

Am i missing something? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: `"<div class='element'> "<img ` notice how img starts after `"`

Comment: Write is as -> document.write("<div class='element'> <img src='images/smileys/" + newArray[i] + "'/>"+ i + "</div>");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra double quote `"` before `img` tag, and you miss another one after `+ i +` :

```
document.write("<div class='element'> "<img src='images/smileys/" + newArray[i] + "'/>"+ i + </div>");
______________________________________^_____________________________________________________^
```

Should be :

```
document.write("<div class='element'><img src='images/smileys/" + newArray[i] + "'/>"+ i +"</div>");
```

Hope this helps.